# Can I build an rpm package that owns a file it does not install?

Tags: linux, uninstall, rpm

I have a situation where I need to create a configuration file filled with default values on initial startup of my application. This is not a typical configuration file where we care deeply about any modifications made by users. During upgrade, I want to simply remove the configuration file so the new code will startup and automatically recreate the config file with defaults again (not my decision - just following orders reluctantly).

Is there a way to build an rpm package that owns a file it does not install so that during uninstall, it will remove this file?

I know that I can always add a pre-remove scriptlet that removes the file - I was just wondering if I can get rpm to do it for me automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the `%ghost` directive:

```
%files
%ghost /path/to/future.file
```

from the [documentation](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html):

> The %ghost Directive
>
> As we mentioned in the Section called The %files
>   List, if a file is specified in the %files list, that file will
>   automatically be included in the package. There are times when a file
>   should be owned by the package but not installed - log files and state
>   files are good examples of cases you might desire this to happen.

Answer (score -3):

No. It is not possible.

BTW: RPM is for delivering apps and library. For configuration management, you should use Ansible.